Транскрибирования русских букв на python
Есть ли готовая библиотека для транслита русских букв на python по правилам яндекса или возможно api?
Правила транслита по яндексу: https://yandex.ru/support/nmaps/app_transliteration.html
Пробовали transliterate, к сожалению не подходит, другие готовые решения по этим правилам не нашли.

"Транскрибация — это точный перевод речи из аудио или видео в текст. Его выполняет человек вручную или с помощью специальных программ.8 Jul 2024" - вы точно применяете термин по назначению?

Если вам нужна транслитерация, то в принципе по вашей ссылке довольно простые правила (если не рассматривать исключения, там всё сложно). Можно просто забить соответствия в словарь и использовать str.maketrans и str.translate для преобразования. Ну там с большими и маленькими буквами отдельно, наверное, надо будет делать или ещё как-то повозиться.
